# Printing an svg to scale, allow to print on multiple pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, printing

I have an svg that I would like to be able to print. My current print function is as follows:

```
      handlePrint() {
          const printWindow = window.open("", "_blank");
          const svgElement : any = document.getElementById(this.getSvgKey());
          const svgText = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svgElement);

          // Remove <rect> elements from the SVG content
          const svgWithoutRects = svgText.replace(/<rect[^>]*>/g, "");

          // Create a new SVG element with the content and style for printing
          const printSvgElement = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
          printSvgElement.setAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");
          printSvgElement.innerHTML = svgWithoutRects;

          // Get the width and height of the SVG content
          const svgWidth = printSvgElement.getAttribute("width");
          const svgHeight = printSvgElement.getAttribute("height");

          // Calculate the scaling factor for 1 pixel to 1mm based on the actual SVG dimensions
          const scale = 25.4 / Math.max(parseFloat(svgWidth!), parseFloat(svgHeight!));

          // Set the width and height of the SVG to match the scaled size
          printSvgElement.setAttribute("width", `${parseFloat(svgWidth!) * scale}mm`);
          printSvgElement.setAttribute("height", `${parseFloat(svgHeight!) * scale}mm`);
          printSvgElement.style["overflow"] = "visible";
          printSvgElement.style["display"] = "inline";
          const pageSize = "A4"; // Change this to the desired paper size

          // Create the HTML content with the updated SVG
          const htmlContent = `
      <html>
        <head>
          <style>
            @media print {
                body {
                    overflow: visible !important
                }
                @page {
                  size: ${pageSize};
                }
              svg {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                transform-origin: top left;
                transform: scale(${scale});
                overflow: visible !important
                display: inline
              }
            }
          </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div>
          ${printSvgElement.outerHTML}
          </div>
        </body>
      </html>
    `;

          // Write the HTML content to the print window and trigger printing
          printWindow!.document.write(htmlContent);
          printWindow!.document.close();
          printWindow!.print();
      }
```

This will attempt to print it so that 1 "pixel" is 1mm at the end.
When i test it, a new window is opened with this content:

[image: full Image]

However the print option seems to be ignoring any overflow and only letting me print this page:

[image: print preview]

How can i make it that the rest of the svg is printed on other pages?

-- UPDATE

Simplified code a little to make it more understandable.I also had a bug on the scale before. This will print to scale but still is printing only the first "column" of pages. Other pages to the right are ignored.

```
    handlePrint() {
        const svgElement : any = document.getElementById(this.getSvgKey());
        const printWindow = window.open("", "_blank");


        const clonedSvg = svgElement.cloneNode(true) as SVGSVGElement;

        // Remove <rect> elements from the cloned SVG
        const rects = clonedSvg.querySelectorAll("rect");
        rects.forEach((rect) => rect.remove());
        printWindow!.document.write(`
    <html>
      <head>
        <style>
          @media print {
            svg {
              width: ${this.props.canvasWidth}mm;
              height: ${this.props.canvasHeight}mm;
              // transform-origin: top left;
              transform: scale(1);
              overflow: auto;
            }
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        ${clonedSvg.outerHTML}
      </body>
    </html>
  `);

        printWindow!.document.close();
        printWindow!.print();
    }
```

Comment: you can't use regex to manipulate XML or HTML documents. Use the DOM.

Comment: The updated version at the bottom already solves that